# Puppet file resource on windows agent don't work, what did i do wrong?

Tags: puppet, puppetmaster, puppet-agent

### Background

- This is the first time i work on puppet
- The puppet master is Linux version...

[image]

- The puppet master host also install Puppet Foreman Server version 1.8.2
- The puppet agent is Window version...

[image]

- When install puppet agent, it has correctly point to the correct FQDN (fully qualified domain name) as i have checked this on foreman on this page.

[image]

- Both agent and master use puppet version 3.8.1
- This is the content in "/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp". in the puppet master From what i understand is that this will make sure that the agent will contain folder "C:/packages" in the puppet agent

[image]

### Problem

I understand that i can test running the puppet agent here without wait for the default waiting time 30 minutes

[image]

This is the result after it has finished.

[image]

However, I go to check in "C:/" and there is no folder "C:/packages" exists in there. I don't know what did i do wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution already.
Instead of putting the code

[image]

in "/etc/puppet/manifests/site.pp"
I have to put it in "/etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/nodes.pp" instead

Answer (score 0):

By simply making a module on your puppet master does not mean it is applied to your hosts.
You have in add the module to forman in the "puppet modules" page, then edit your host within forman and add the module.

Y

Comment: Could you please teach me where is the "puppet modules" page in foreman.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/5qehd.png